Strong Maximum principle Evans Theorem 4
Hello everybody im recently studying PDES and this theorem in particular. I'm having trouble in demonstrating in a rigorous way the highlited sentence. I mean i know it's possible, but i would like to show it explicitly. Any help is apreciated. The hypothesis and the demonstration are attached.
Statement and Hypothesis:

Demonstration:


Please don't use images as text.

I'm really sorry this is my first question. Thank's for the feedback and correction.

We're supposing $C$ is not empty, so pick $x\in C$. $V$ cannot be empty either (otherwise by continuity $u\equiv M$ on $\overline U$). Pick $x'\in V$, and use connectedness of $U$ to pick a continuous function $f:[0,1]\to U$ such that $f(0) = x'$ and $f(1) = x$. Let now $t_0 = \inf\{t\in [0,1]\mid f(t)\in C\} > 0$. then $x_0 = f(t_0)\in C$. Set $\varepsilon = d(x_0,\partial U) > 0$. By continuity of $f$, there exists $\delta > 0$ (we can suppose $\delta < t_0$) such that $\forall t\in (t_0-\delta,t_0+\delta)$, $d(f(t),f(t_0)) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. It now suffices to consider $y = f(t_0-\frac\delta 2) \in V$, as $d(y,C) < \frac \varepsilon 2 < d(y,\partial U)$.

Thank you for your answear it was really helpfull. Appreciate it
